# How to get values of object in firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to implement code in Firestore which will get the values of a specific object inside a doc in firestore, unfortunently i couldnt find the way to do it.

This is my query code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection("confirmed-appointments")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let service = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          service.push(doc.data());
        });
        console.log("Services: ", service[0].servicesSelected); //Checking if i can get the serviceSelected Obj
      });
  }, []);
```

This is a image of the firestore:
[image: Firestore collection]

What i want is to get the data of the Red circle object, move it to a local object in the code and then present its data inside the app.

any suggestions?

Comment: `doc.data().servicesSelected` did you get data on this code ?

Comment: No i got undefined for that

Comment: did you check if you're getting data inside your snapshot ?

Comment: Yes, if im calling service and not serviceSelected im getting all the data from the doc, the log looks like the image attached

Comment: Please post what data you're receiving in service

Comment: Could you please show the output of `console.log(doc.data())`? I can see that you have some arrays (`2`) in place within your `10` document, so using `doc.data().servicesSelected` may not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the above images, document *10* contains an array, which means that you will need to index into that array in order to get its elements. You can leverage the following code to fetch the `servicesSelected` object fields:

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc(uid)
  .collection("confirmed-appointments")
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {

    //let service = [];
    console.log('Total confirmed appointments: ', querySnapshot.size);

    querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
      console.log("Services Selected: ", documentSnapshot.data().YOUR_ARRAY[1].servicesSelected); 

      //service.push(documentSnapshot.data());
      //console.log('Appointment ID: ', documentSnapshot.id, documentSnapshot.data()); 

    });
  });
```

Note that I assume that `servicesSelected` lives at index 1 of `YOUR_ARRAY` (replace `YOUR_ARRAY` with its actual name).

You can refer to the officially recommended [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage) for more details about React Native for Firebase.